# Start FragmentActivity from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

How can I start a FragmentActivity from an Activity?

My MainActivity is a splash screen and I want to star a FragmentActivity next.

I need something instead of, for example:

```
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.manager.MyFragmentActivity"));
```

TIA.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your first Activity call:

```
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MyFragmentActivity.class));
```

Note: Make sure to register your `MyFragmentActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**Edit:** This training article on [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent) should be helpful to you.

Comment: I tried to do the same, in android studio my fragment is not displayed in the auto-complete options. Also, on adding it without the auto-complete option, its showing an error that it is not assignable. What do I do?