# Error: MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

First, I watched out here: [Start FragmentActivity from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757730/start-fragmentactivity-from-activity) and now I have the following problem:

**MapsActivity:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
...
```

and want to start it out of the **MainActivity** with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
```

The activity is registered in Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="de.xbjoernx.gapp.MapsActivity"></activity>
```

## Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.xbjoernx.gapp/de.xbjoernx.gapp.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:323)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
        at de.xbjoernx.gapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
        ... 20 more
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Thanks so far :)

Comment: Can you try with just `<activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>` ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment   <--- you have to decide which one you are going to use.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

as you are extending `FragmentActivity` which indicates you are using Support library v4 compatible with lower version of android. Replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment` inside your xml file. `SupportMapFragment` is the one to use with the Android Support package. `MapFragment` is for the native API Level 11 version of fragments.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect :) Just use com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: @Bhavesh Patadiya I already have SupportMapFragment in my xml file but I still have same issue:  **Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment**