# Cannot convert type 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' to 'Android.Gms.Maps.MapFragment'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and am recoding a Google Maps application to use Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments with a View Pager.

Here is my code:

```
private void InitMapFragment()
{
    _mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as MapFragment;
    if (_mapFragment == null)
    {
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

        FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        _mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapWithOverlay, _mapFragment, "map");
        fragTx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Because I am now extending the Activity to use Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, I am getting the following errors when compiling:

> Error CS0039: Cannot convert type 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' to
>   'Android.Gms.Maps.MapFragment' via a reference conversion, boxing
>   conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type
>   conversion (CS0039)

At the line:

```
_mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as MapFragment
```

As well as:

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction' to
>   'Android.App.FragmentTransaction' (CS0029)

At the line:

```
FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
```

Can I have some help to get this code working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227540/error-mapfragment-cannot-be-cast-to-android-support-v4-app-fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments instead of using MapFragment at

```
_mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
```

use SupportMapFragment

```
_mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
```

Hope that helps!

You should have android.support.v4.jar in your libs folder and in the project build path

Comment: What do I need to do to use the SupportMapFragment rather than the MapFragment?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing classes that use the support library fragments with classes that aren't built off that hierarchy (and work only on 3.0+).  You can't do that.  You need to use SupportMapFragment instead of map fragment.

Comment: What reference do I need to use SupportMapFragment?